# Android localization bug with radio buttons?

Tags: android, localization

I have an Android app that is localized for English and Spanish. When you install in English and view it in English, everything works. When you install it in Spanish (the phone's locale is set to Spanish before APK install) and view it in Spanish, everything works. The oddities happen when you install it in one language, flip to the other and then run the app. The radio button text refuses to change from the language it was on install. I have verified that the strings are correct in both strings.xml files, and it only seems to be happening with the text for radio buttons. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [reported bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13252).